# Adding a hovering option to my buttons in a class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add a hovering option for multiple buttons which I have already achieved, but I would like to do it in a class to save me adding the option to each button individually.
I'm coding in python and using tkinter for my GUI.

```
class GUIButtons():
    def __init__(self, window):
         self.window = window

         self.Calculate = Button(window, command=GetUnits, text="Calculate", width = 19, background = "dark blue", fg="white")
         self.Calculate.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=NSEW)

         self.ShowMethod = Button(window, command=ShowMethod, text="Show method", width = 19, background = "darkblue", fg="white")
         self.ShowMethod.grid(row=1, column= 5, sticky=NSEW)

         self.Submit = Button(window, command = lambda: GetCoordinate(Message), text="Submit", width = 6, height = 1, background = "dark blue", fg="white", font = 11)
         self.Submit.grid(row=3, column = 3, sticky = NSEW)

         self.Displacement = Button(window, text="Displacement", background = "Dark Blue", fg="white", font=11)
         self.Displacement.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky= N)
```

Not sure how to bind the hover option just once for it to apply for all my buttons.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Instance and Class Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

> But Tkinter also allows you to create bindings on the class and
> application level; in fact, you can create bindings on four different
> levels:
>
> - the widget class, using **bind_class** (this is used by Tkinter to provide
>   standard bindings)

and example

> By the way, if you really want to change the behavior of all text
> widgets in your application, here’s how to use the bind_class method:
>
> top.**bind_class**("Text", "", lambda e: None)

So using `bind_class` with `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` you can do it.

--

**EDIT:** example - when mouse `enter/hover` any button then `test()` will be called.

```
from tkinter import *

# ---

def test(event):
    print(event)

# ---

window = Tk()

# created befor binding
Button(window, text="Button #1").pack()
Button(window, text="Button #2").pack()
Button(window, text="Button #3").pack()

window.bind_class('Button', '<Enter>', test)

# created after binding
Button(window, text="Button #4").pack()

window.mainloop()
```

--

You can also create own Widget to change existing Widget.

Red button:

```
from tkinter import *

# ---

class RedButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, parent, **options):
        Button.__init__(self, parent, **options)
        self['bg'] = 'red'
        # or
        #self.config(bg='red')

# ---
        
window = Tk()

RedButton(window, text="Button #1").pack()
RedButton(window, text="Button #2").pack()
RedButton(window, text="Button #3").pack()

window.mainloop()
```

or

```
class RedButton(Button):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, **options):
        Button.__init__(self, parent, bg='red', **options)
```

--

**EDIT:**

If you need to change only button colors on hover then you don't need to bind function. Button has `activebackground=` and `activeforeground=`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="HOVER", activebackground='blue', activeforeground='red')
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

see [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

**EDIT**: it can behave different on Windows, Linux and OS X

Comment: Hi there, thanks for taking the time to help with my code. I'm a little confused what you have suggested. I would like to create a hover feature for all my buttons without doing it to each one individually, hence the class. I am new to python so I apologise if none of this is making sense.

Comment: you can use `bind_class('Button', '<Enter>', function_name)` to bind `<Enter>` event to all `Button`  - and it will call `function_name` when mouse `enter/hover` button.

Comment: or maybe you thing about something different when you say  "hover feature"

Comment: Hi again, thanks for those examples, they were very helpful. I have now got all my buttons customised with that class. However I am still struggling with the hover feature. I would like my buttons to also change colour when the mouse hovers over the buttons but when i try to .bind() i get an error message saying 'object has no attribute bind'

Comment: add code to pastebin.org and put link. If you need to change only hover color then use `activeforeground=` and `activebackground=`

Comment: That code only changes colour of buttons once it has been clicked, I would like to change colour when the mouse cursor is just hovering over the button.

Comment: it changes color when I hover button. Maybe it behaves different on Linux, Window and OS X. I use Linux.

Comment: Good point, thanks for helping me with my other issues though, you have been very helpful.